# Should I create a new .py script for unit tests?

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, testing, xsd-1.1

I have written a Python script for parsing and validating `XML` files against an `.XSD` schema (and some other constraints), and I am about to write tests for it. I was thinking of using Python's `unittest` because it is built in and has assertions that I am familiar with. I have never tested with Python before, but have done JUnit testing with Java. I was wondering if I should create a new .py script for the tests?

Comment: Technically asking for tips/suggestions is [off-topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) since it can lead to opinionated answers and software recommendation.

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [Py.test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/) instead of the built-in `unittest` module -- it's way more ergonomic.

With Py.test, you'd have a separate `test_foo.py` file (it discovers test-containing files by default by a `test_` prefix).

Comment: So I think I have confused myself on the concept of unit testing. The test I will be writing will be basically a bunch of different xml and make sure that all errors can be caught. The test will be called on one function, but that function calls a lot of helper functions. Should I still be using unitests/py.tests? Thanks.

Comment: You'd write separate test functions for those use cases - or you can be fancy with the Py.test [`parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) fixture and just have a list of test files and expected errors, etc. :)